# How to prove gamma function inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, special-functions, gamma-function

I am struggling with the inequality below: $$\ln\Gamma(x+1) - 2\ln\Gamma\left(\frac 12 x + \frac 12\right)\geq \ln(\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor !)-2\ln\left(\left\lfloor \frac x2 \right\rfloor !\right)$$
I know that
$$\ln\Gamma(x+1)\geq\ln(\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor !)$$
so that part is easy to get. However, I am unsure of how to proceed with the next term. Any help is appreciated! Additionally, what about the flip side?

$$\ln\Gamma(x) - 2\ln\Gamma\left(\frac 12 x + \frac 12\right)\leq \ln(\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor !)-2\ln\left(\left\lfloor \frac x2 \right\rfloor !\right)$$
How would I prove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After exponentiation we get:

$$ \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^2}\ge \frac{\Gamma(\lfloor x\rfloor +1)}{\Gamma(\lfloor \frac{x}{2}\rfloor +1)^2} $$

it gets directly obvious, since :
$$ {\Gamma(x+1)}\ge {\Gamma(\lfloor x\rfloor +1)}$$

for $x>0$,

and also:

$$ \Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+\frac12) \le \Gamma(\lfloor \frac{x}{2}\rfloor +1\rfloor).$$

for $x>0$.

Comment: I added an edit above. The same question had a part 2, which I am also confused about. Can you please take a look and see what you can do?